# What's the purpose of this flag, if it gets declined?

Tags: discussion, flagging

When flagging, there is available the following flag reason:

[image: VLQ flag]

It states:

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

But the above flag got denied with the following motivation:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Then my question is: when is it appropriate to use this flag?

Comment: "I'm having this problem, too" mode=ON. The OP's concern is very valid. Personally, I avoid using this flag at all. Too many of those get rejected, and I see no reason to spoil my flag statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This flag is supposed to be used for answer *completely* devoid of useful content. When an answer is just bad, the usual way to handle it is downvote it. Then the community can vote to delete an answer without requiring mod intervention.

This difference is a very subjective one. Which answers are so bad they need to go immediately by mod fiat and which can stay on the site and be handled through the community is decided by mods on a case-by-case basis. There is no strict guideline for this.

Please don't feel bad when such a flag gets rejected. Your help is always appreciated.

Comment: I don't feel bad, I'm trying to understand. I thought that such vote would put the question in the "low quality" review queue